# Why file contents are getting lost that I have uploaded and now trying to download the same?

Tags: php

I am uploading .docx and .txt files from a html form. files are getting uploaded into specified folder. Then I saved path of that folder to the database. Now then I fetched all the records from database into tabular format.I got a column link in which I am got link to the file i uploaded previously but now when i click that link my file is getting download but not its contents.
I am storing file path to database as

```
$link='<a href="'.$target_dir.'">'.basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]).'</a>'; // Hyperlink to file.
```

Is this wrong?

I am using table row as

```
<td>".'<a href="download.php? filename='.$name.'"> Download</a>'."</td>
```

here `$name` is `$name=$row['filename'];`

Can anyone help?
here is my php file where i'm fetching records from database

`To Download Resume Click on the link :

```
  include ('./config.php');
  global $conn; // Create connection
     $query="select * from candidate_regi";
     $result = $conn->query($query);
    echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='3' align='centre' width='70%'>
                <tr align='centre'>
                <th>CANDIDATE_ID</th>
                <th>FULL_NAME</th>
                <th>ADDRESS</th>
                <th>CONTACT</th>
                <th>QUALIFICATION</th>
                <th>EMAIL-ID</th>
                <th>RESUME_NAME</th>
                <th>RESUME_PATH</th>

                </tr>";
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                 $name=$row['filename'];
                 $type=$row['filepath'];
             echo "<tr ALIGN='CENTER'>
                   <td>".$row['candidate_id']."</td>
                   <td>".$row['full_name']."</td>
                   <td>".$row['address']."</td>
                   <td>".$row['contact']."</td>
                   <td>".$row['qualification']."</td>
                   <td>".$row['email']."</td>
                   <td>".$row['filename']."</td>
                   <td>".'<a href="dw1.php?filename=' . $name . '">download</a>'."</td>

                   </tr>";
             }
              echo "</table>";  }?>
```

Comment: I doubt that the error resides within the saving of the file name in the database, and more likely resides in the **headers** that you return when you handle the download request.

Comment: Start by showing an example of the filename you have stored on the database, then show the code you use to create the HTML for the clickable link. The whole path to the directories holding the files would also be useful

Comment: You have a space in your url after the ? - try removing that

Comment: @bhutton that is not a problem